# magento 500 error in frontend backend admin working properly

Tags: magento-1.9, frontend-error

exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Mage_Ves_Priceslider_Block_Ajax' in /home/eindia1/public_html/app/Mage.php:595

```
Stack trace:
#0 /home/eindia1/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...')
#1 /home/eindia1/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('ves_priceslider...', Array)
#2 /home/eindia1/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('ves_priceslider...', 'ajaxSlider')
#3 /home/eindia1/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('ves_priceslider...', 'ajaxSlider')
#4 /home/eindia1/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#5 /home/eindia1/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#6 /home/eindia1/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#7 /home/eindia1/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/CategoryController.php(148): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#8 /home/eindia1/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Catalog_CategoryController->viewAction()
#9 /home/eindia1/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#10 /home/eindia1/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#11 /home/eindia1/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#12 /home/eindia1/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#13 /home/eindia1/public_html/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#14 {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to any extension conflict that's why showing this error, Please find this extension in module file(app/etc/modules) and disable "Priceslider_Block_Ajax" extension then go to cache management and clear cache and reload your front end web page. Hope this will help you.